# What does the A stand for in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

Does anyone know what the acronym IDEA stand for?
I would assume Integrated Development Environment, then maybe Application?
Also does Intellij stand for anything?

Comment: Uhm, what a strange question... Also, it is now JetBrains, not Intellij anymore. Maybe Advanced? But anyway, I think it is an intended pun. Ultimately, I have no... Idea...

Comment: They still call the product IntelliJ IDEA, even if the company is named JetBrains now.

Comment: IBM Developed Eclipse Again ;)

Comment: I assume its a cross between `idea` for creativity and `IDE` https://www.jetbrains.com/company/history.jsp

Comment: It's so that if anyone says "why are you using Eclipse?", you can say "I have NO IDEA".

Comment: @Reimeus. IntelliJ is actually based on an old NetBeans version.

Comment: One Quora user thinks it stands for "Awesome". http://www.quora.com/IntelliJ-IDEA/What-does-the-A-in-Intellij-IDEA-stand-for

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an official answer and this question doesn't suit stackoverflow, so instead of "answering" I'll leave this link in comments for your procrastination hunger delight ;) http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/3442730?tstart=0

Answer (score 48):

Intelli  ===>  Intelligent

J ===> Java

Idea  ===>IDE that is Advanced or  Idea just means idea( I have a good idea ...like this ) ...

//The Idea has Double meaning

Comment: Even if this is wrong, it should be the right answer. :)

Answer (score 33):

Maxim Shafirov (the CEO of JetBrains), made the following comment prior to 2005, in a now deleted official JetBrains news article, published online:

> I have always thought that it's a play on words that (1) it's an IDE,
>   and (2) "idea" is a nice sounding word which contains "IDE".

Reference:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206938805-IDEA-acronym-?page=1#community_comment_207115259

So, based on the only thing I've seen that looks like actual evidence, I think a good answer may be "it probably isn't intended to mean anything"

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/space/2020/12/16/space-ama-session/ gives more explanation about the names JetBrains, IntelliJ IDEA, and so on.

Answer (score 17):

It stands for application, but is mostly a play on words giving the IDE's name a creative appeal by just turning the widely-used 'IDE' (Integrated Development Environment) into IDEA (like "I have a brilliant idea!").

Answer (score -2):

I think it refers to APache2 license that intellij ide released under that license so will be : Integrated Development Environment Apache

Answer (score -2):

Given that the acronym 'IDEA' comes before the word 'Brain', it only makes sense for it to read as: 'The JetBrains Idea'. It's probably just a play of words.

Comment: what's the point of posting this when Chris' answer already exists?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).